# Under what circumstances would db.define_table() return None

Tags: web2py, data-access-layer

This code was working fine but now it fails because the db.define_table() returns `None`.

```
table = db.define_table('DatabaseModel', Field('TableName'))  # This is not working now
for t in db.tables:
    table.update_or_insert(TableName=t)
```

The only thing that I have changed that might have affected it was setting `migrate = false` in appconfig.ini. I have changed it back but to no avail.

What could stop `db.define_table` from working?

(I am using this to create an in-memory table which I populate with a list of actual tables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably also set `DAL(..., lazy_tables=True)`, in which case, `db.define_table()` returns `None` rather than a `Table` object, as the table is not actually created until first accessed via `db.tablename`.

Given your code, there is no benefit to setting `lazy_tables=True`, as all tables are accessed (and therefore created) immediately after definition anyway.

Comment: You are Brilliant! That's exactly what I did. Thank you.